# node.js's "bad" packages?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am getting my hands on node.js and its NPM valuable service. I tried installing [this](https://github.com/dylang/shortid) package and, by reading the documentation, it says that to generate a short id, this code needed:

```
shortId.generate();
```

that means that to use the ID, I would need something like this.

```
var id = shortId.generate();
res.end(id);
```

I hope I am not making a mistake here, but I thought the correct way to do things asynchronously was to use callbacks? And do something like:

```
shortId.generate(function(val){
  res.end(val);
});
```

Can anyone please help me clarifying this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the code in your example is synchronous.  Node.JS has strength from it's asynchronous code, but not absolutely everything is asynchronous.

Mostly, the asynchronous code is usful for blocking IO.

Answer (score 1):

As you could see from that module [source code](https://github.com/dylang/shortid/blob/master/shortid.js#L32) it does not perform any i/o at all while generating the id.

Callbacks in node are used when i/o takes place, so the program does not wait until the operation is performed, giving a function to be called when the i/o finishes.

Answer (score 0):

The `shortId.generate` function is blocking, so it doesn't provide a callback for the result.

This makes sense in this case, because the unique ID generation isn't a heavy operation. If it was, you could adjust the code to enable a callback methodology.

Callbacks are definitely common though! For example, your web application wants to save an object to the server. You could be non-blocking here by adding a callback to the save function, so you could return a response sooner than the object has been written to disk/cache.

I recommend reading [art of node](https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node) for some great examples of blocking vs. non-blocking. :)